# Cannot select my own key for encryption

Tags: gpg4win

When using the context menu to encrypt a file, my own certificate is not listed in the list, despite having successfully imported it and marked it as my own. I see it in the My Certificates tab in Kleopatra, but it seems to not exist when trying to encrypt a file. What gives?

Comment: Chris (or anyone else), did you figure this one out? I am faced with the same issue. I thought maybe I would try removing my own cert and re-adding it, however I can't do that either. I have the same result as this bug shown here [Kleopatra Bug 331129](http://mail.kde.org/pipermail/kdepim-bugs/2014-February/091875.html) . I'm not sure if they are related at all

Comment: I never found an answer. I later had to reinstall and it worked fine.